# return statement that checks the first two characters before proceeding

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
return ship.DefenseType?.PropulsionMethod != null
    ? new BattleMethod(ship.DefenseType.PropulsionMethod)
    : null;
```

Hi, my current return statement, above, is returning a Propulsion method if it's not null.  However, my database has different types of 
propulsion methods denoted by the first 2 letters in the field(PK, PA, PT, etc).

How can I check to make sure that the PropulsionMethod starts with "PK" before going further into the return statement?

In pseudo code, it might look something like this:

```
if (ship.DefenseType?.PropulsionMethod).startsWith("PK") 
        && ship.DefenseType?.PropulsionMethod != null)
{
    return new BattleMethod(ship.DefenseType.PropulsionMethod)
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

I tried

```
return ship.DefenseType?.PropulsionMethod != null &&
    ship.DefenseType?.PropulsionMethod.StartsWith("PK")
    ? new BattleMethod(ship.DefenseType.PropulsionMethod)
    : null;
```

But I get this error:

> operator && cannot be applied to operands of type bool and bool?

Comment: Make a factory class

Comment: And what is the problem with your solution?  In what way does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this condition too:

```
    return ship.DefenseType?.PropulsionMethod != null 
    && ship.DefenseType?.PropulsionMethod.StartsWith("PK")
 ? new BattleMethod(ship.DefenseType.PropulsionMethod) : null;
```

As the operator is `&&` so the second condition will be evaluated if the first one was true (not null in this case).

Comment: Maybe `ship.DefenseType?.PropulsionMethod?.StartsWith(...)` will be enough?

Comment: @AleksAndreev thanks, it won't be as if it is null, null is returned, otherwise a class of `BattleMethod` not  the value of `PropulsionMethod`. in this case we will still need an `if` to check if the value is null or we can return a `BattleMethod`

Comment: I get this error: operator && cannot be applied to operands of type bool and bool?

Comment: it is a silly error as && is only for bool types, and you should get an error if they were not boolean. however try to put your conditions in parentheses `(...&&...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can compare nullable bool directly with `true`:

```
return ship.DefenseType?.PropulsionMethod?.StartsWith("PK") == true
    ? new BattleMethod(ship.DefenseType.PropulsionMethod)
    : null;
```